# AJAX and the Facebook API

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook-graph-api

Let's say I want to use this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  success: function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(key, val) {
      var shareCount = val["share"]["share_count"];
      if (shareCount > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something
        }, 0000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something else
        }, 0000);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Which would get a like count from Facebook. Now what if the API is down / the visitor can't access it (unlikely, but what if) or throws back an error like:

```
{
 "error": {
    "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": true,
    "code": 4,
    "fbtrace_id": ""
  }
}
```

How would I go about displaying an error message if either were to happen?

`error: function(result)`

Comment: Adding error callback to the $.ajax parameter object? Though you may want to check jquery ajax docs (I think they changed some of callbacks names)

Comment: ideally, you cache the results anyway, to avoid hitting rate limits. never do api calls on every single user hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an error-function to be called if the request fails for some reason

```
$.ajax({
  url: apiUrl,
  success: function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(key, val) {
      var shareCount = val["share"]["share_count"];
      if (shareCount > 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something
        }, 0000);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
        // Do something else
        }, 0000);
      }
    });
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Do something with the error message
    alert('There was a problem fetching likes from facebook');
  },
});
```